# Regex to exclude 1 word out of a regex code

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex expert to help out on this one.  Examples I've found on here and the net I cant seem to get right.  I'm using PHP and I have the following regex expression

```
/([^a-zA-Z0-9])GC([A-Z0-9]+)/
```

This matches items like GCABCD GC123A, etc.  What i need to do is EXCLUDE GCSTATS from this.  So basically I want it to work just as it has, except, ignore GCSTATS in the regex.

Comment: Your regex does not work if the search text starts with GC...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to add this after GC: (?!STATS). It's a negative lookahead construction.
So your regex should be

```
/([^a-zA-Z0-9]*)GC(?!STATS)([A-Z0-9]+)/
```

p.s. or try **`?<!`**

Answer (score 0):

[Regex assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) is what you need. This also works if the search text starts with GC...

```
/(?<![A-Za-z0-9])GC(?!STATS)[A-Z0-9]+/
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9])GC((?!STATS)[A-Z0-9]+)
```

More Information is available at [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)